# How pull in fields value from created parameter

Tags: ssrs-2012

I created a parameter [GroupID] that is used to query several datasets in my SSRS report.  It is using the field [GroupID] from my GroupList_Rolling12 dataset.  An example of [GroupID] is 77610N.  When 77610N is selected, all of my datasets are correctly 'filtering' for this [GroupID].

I now need to create a text box that returns the [GroupName] of [GroupID].  In other words, when 77610N is selected from my GroupID parameter, I want the [GroupName] that is associated with the selected GroupID parameter to display.

I'm still very new to SSRS and cannot figure this out.  I tried creating the expression =First(Fields!GroupName.Value, "GroupList_Rolling12") but that did not work since it simply returns the first value from the query.

I also tried =First(Parameters!GroupID.Value(0)) but this also did not work

I also tried this expression =Lookup(Fields!GroupID.Value, Fields!GroupID.Value, Fields!GroupName.Value, "GroupList_Rolling12")
)

Can you please help?

Comment: Is '77610N' the parameter `Value` or the `Label` or both? The parameter label is what the user sees, the value is normally the value you want to filter with. Also, is the textbox going to be inside a tablix or it is standalone as this will make difference on the approach? And finally, is your parameter set to be multi-value or single value?

Comment: 77610N is the Value.  GroupName is the Lable (which the user sees when they select the parameter value).  The textbox I'm trying to create is going to be in a header.  The GroupID parameter is also set to be single value only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reference the parameter label directly like this

```
=Parameters!GroupID.Label
```

There is no need to put the index on the end (`=Parameters!GroupID.Label(0)`) unless your parameter is multi-value, in which case it would select the first selected entry.